# Simple software to show and modify GPS tracks

Tags: software-recommendation, gps

I have GPS tracks (in gpx format) that I usually use to geotag photos. Is there a simple software to view these tracks (i.e.: not use Google Earth)? A bonus would be simple modification, like deleting waypoints. TangoGPS seems to offer GPS track import only in connection with geotagging for pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Viking](https://snapcraft.io/viking-gps) - you can download and edit your tracks, and also add OpenStreetMaps, Terraserver or DEM layers. It also allows to have georeferenced map layers and some other features.

Comment: Viking is still a bit too complex for my taste (having layers etc.) but it certainly can do everything I want and is fairly simple to use. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Instead of installing software I used the free online [GPX Studio](https://gpx.studio/) which suited my purposes just fine (combining 3 GPX files and deleting a few waypoints). For the record I have no affiliation to the software, just a happy user.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [Merkaartor](http://merkaartor.be/) (in the [repos](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/merkaartor/)) to be the simplest. But [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) is the most used and widespread, it's a PITA to find the right version to use.

I'd say give Merkaartor a shot :)

Comment: Josm allows upload into openstreetmap

Comment: Thanks, merkaartor (there was an "r" missing) looks powerful (as does JOSM which I tried a while ago), but is not the kind of "simple" software I had in mind. I'd love to have something like tangoGPS or the emerillon map viewer, but simply with the additional feature to show gps tracks...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `GPSPrune`. It is a Java application and support multiple platforms. I used it in Ubuntu, Windows and MacOS.

Myself don't like multiple workflow and prefer sticking to same app where ever PC available to process and upload to OSM.